# Trying to hide a submenu link which is created by Co-authors Plus plugin

Tags: admin

I cannot hide this menu here (see picture) and I don't what else to do, please help. Apparently, I cannot find the correct hook to do achieve that.

example:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'hide_guest_authors_link_from_backend');

function hide_guest_authors_link_from_backend() { ?> 
  <script>
    document.querySelector("li a[href='users.php?page=view-guest-authors']").style.display = 'none';
  </script>
<?php 
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: which plugin are you using? please explain with more information.

Comment: @Dilip Gupta: I just said in the title: Co-Authors Plus https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/ :)

Answer (score 0):

I did search for it, you just need to remove the action called `action_admin_menu`. just add this line in your theme's functions.php file.

```
remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'action_admin_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked with this:

```
remove_submenu_page( 'users.php', 'view-guest-authors' );
```